# 1st image is displaying but after uploading 2nd not displaying

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to upload images in a list using input file and display it.

My code displays the 1st upload but after the 2nd upload it doesn't display.

```
function DisImg() {

    const [file, setFile] = useState([]);

    function handleChange(e) {
        let sel = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
        setFile(prevV => [
            ...prevV, sel
        ]);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Input type="file" onChange={handleChange}>Choose file</Input>
            {
                file.map(() => {
                    return <img src={file} alt="documents" height="50px" width="50px" />
                })
            }
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the values stored in the `file` array. You pass `file` directly to the `src` of the image.

[.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) provides you with the current value when you're mapping over the `file` array.

```js
{file.map((src) => {
  return <img src={src} alt="documents" height="50px" width="50px" />;
})}
```

Answer (score 2):

add source variable like `url`, also add `index` variable as a unique `key` that will help to track.

```
<Input type="file" onChange={handleChange}>Choose file</Input>
            {file.map((url,index) => {
                    return <img src={url} key={index} alt="documents" height="50px" width="50px" />
                })
            }
```